# Environment variable is null in Java test during mvn build on Mac

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, macos-big-sur

I have different Java test behaviours (probably after a MacOS update to Big Sur 11.2.3 or another system).

My JUnit test requires the variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac and LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Ubuntu (mvn surefire is used, see below) to find some dylibs / shared objects.

Test works in IntelliJ without any problems on both OS.
But during the mvn build the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable (System.getenv(..)) is null and the test fails on Mac (on Ubuntu it works). Starting mvn with '-X' shows that surefire sets the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but later it is still null.

I am using maven-3.6.3, surefire 3.0.0-M5 and OpenJDK 11.0.10.

Any ideas, how I can with the environment issue?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <environmentVariables>
            <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${basedir}/src/main/resources/libs</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>
            <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>${basedir}/src/main/resources/libs</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls report a bug in our [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE) and attach your project in ZIP. We need to reproduce it and debug the plugin but the project is required.